# How to select good exercises?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, self-learning, learning

I'm studying on Rudin "Principles of of Mathematical Analysis" which I begin to find as a good and complete reference.

1. I wonder how many exercises shall I do at the end of each chapter ?
2. In case of time shortage, how can I select the most relevant ones ?
3. Is it ok to wait until the end of each chapter to start exercising ?

Comment: I am afraid that there is no easy answer. This is one of the major advantages of following a course over self-studying: in the first case, an instructor is choosing the exercises for you. I guess that only your own experience can help you here.

Comment: (1) As many as you feel will help you to better understand that chapter. (2) No answer. (3) No.

Comment: @Timbuc Thank you very much!